# Switch between different output versions compiled from the same LaTeX source

Tags: compiling, conditionals

For programming in C, it is quite common to switch between creating debug- and release-versions by passing a command line argument to the compiler.

I would like to have something similar for `pdflatex`. Optimally, there would be conditional parts within the source LaTeX file depending on some variable, and then the switching between the versions can be done by somehow setting this variable at the command-line invocation of `pdflatex`.

Is it possible to achieve something like this? What's the easiest / cleanest way?

Comment: `pdflatex '\def\zz{yes}\input' mainfile`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thank you, that is easier than I thought. I'm declaring my variable internally via `\newboolean{variable}`, which needs the package `ifthen`. Is is also possible to assign such a variable a value from the command line?

Comment: @azimut That's what `'\def\zz{yes}\input'` does. Alternatively, you could write a small bash script for example who finds the value of the variable in the `tex` file and compile accordingly.

Comment: Use `arara`, maybe? There is `-draftmode` but I don't think it is what you want.

Comment: @cfr: It's not about a draft version. I would like to  control from the command line to include certain parts of the document or not.

Comment: That's why I said I didn't think that was what you wanted and suggested `arara`.

Comment: @anderstood: I have in my file the lines `\usepackage{ifthen}` and `\newboolean{var}`. If I compile this with `'pdflatex \def\var{yes}\input'` (or `pdflatex '\def\var{true}\input'`, then `var` seems still to be set to `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand{\foo}[1]{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{True}}{gagagag}{blablabla}% 
}

\begin{document} 
\foo{\val} 
\end{document}
```

yields `gagagag` when compiled with

```
pdflatex '\def\val{True}\input' file.tex
```

and `blablabla` when compiled with

```
pdflatex '\def\val{something else}\input' temp.tex
```

(Credits to  David Carlisle, see comments.)