# Hide/Show Solution for Problems

Tags: environments, conditionals, printing

There are too many options for "Solution/Answer" environments which we can use and I am adopting [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19947/example-solution-environment) for my "big" project that I am doing.

At the moment, it looks like the easiest one for me to implement, but there is just one function to be explored. How can I show/hide the `solution` environment, so that I can have a `teachers'` version and a `students'` version?

When the solutions are hidden, preferably that the space I used for these content are "reserved."

Thanks.

Comment: Hope it's okay that I'm sneeaking in here that I have made a package called [exercisebank](http://ctan.org/pkg/exercisebank) which is pretty light weight and has an easy `\DisplaySolutions` command that you toggle it with :)

Comment: What do you mean by "reserved" space?

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman Sorry if I wasn't clear. What I meant is that simply in the students version, the solutions are "invisible" and replaced using white space. So if a solution goes on across two pages, in the students version, they simply see white space carried over to the "next page" with more white space.

Comment: Updated my answer, this should work :)

Comment: OP has posted a [MWE example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/434143/107497), which I've encouraged to be edited into this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tcolorbox` offers `lowerbox` option to make visible or not their lower parts. This is a little example to show how it works. This option could be combined with `recording` mechanisms to store and later on show solutions (an example in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/224429/1952)).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\NewTColorBox[auto counter]{exercise}{+O{}}{%
        enhanced, breakable,
        coltitle=black, 
        fonttitle=\bfseries,
        title={Exercise~\thetcbcounter:},
        attach title to upper=\quad,
        before lower={\textbf{Solution~\thetcbcounter:\quad}},
        #1}

\tcbset{student/.style={lowerbox=invisible}}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}
Type some nice problem, not too long.
\tcblower       
An this is the solution
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}[student]
\lipsum[1]
\tcblower 
\lipsum[1]
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}[student]
\lipsum[2]
\tcblower 
\lipsum[3]
\end{exercise}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Tried this version with whole document, and got this error: ! pdfTeX error (setup): \pdfminorversion cannot be changed after data is written to the PDF file.

Comment: Further, how do I control `[student]` as a general global option? I don't want to add/delete `[student]` every time when I compile the PDF. Thanks.

Comment: @ChenStatsYu About the error, I have no idea.

Comment: @ChenStatsYu The easiest way for printing or not answer would be to forget `student` option and include `lowerbox=invisible` declaration inside `exercise` definition.  This way all answer will be hidden. Whan you want to show them, comment out `lowerbox` line (or change it to `lowerbox=visible`) and compile again. If you want to decide from command line look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239411/switch-between-different-output-versions-compiled-from-the-same-latex-source?noredirect=1&lq=1 or similar questions.

Comment: Thanks. This looks like the best option for me to adapt and move forward.

Comment: One more question, where would I find the options for `color`? I have been looking at the codes, but it does not seem to be there. Can't see `grey` or anything similar. Is it possible to have different color for `lowerbox` too?

Comment: `colback=white` changes all color, is it possible to do different color for `lowerbox` only??

Comment: @ChenStatsYu You should look for `bicolor` and `colbacklower` at [tcolorbox](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tcolorbox) documentation.

Answer (score 3):

You can put the teacher's section between a block of comment using the package `comment`.

```
\begin{comment}
    ...
    text
    ...
\end{comment}
```

Then you can compile a version for students. If you want to compile the teacher's version just delete the `\begin{comment}` and `\end{comment}`.

You can do exactly what you want using `\includecomment{teacher}` or `\excludecomment{teacher}` with the text inside the block `teacher`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{comment}

\begin{document}

Text not commented

\includecomment{teacher}
\begin{teacher}
text
\end{teacher}

Text not commented

\end{document}
```

Now for the reserved space you desire one simple workaround is use the `vspace{}` command.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{comment}

\begin{document}

Text not commented

\excludecomment{teacher}
\begin{teacher}
text
\end{teacher}
\vspace{3cm}

Text not commented

\end{document}
```

The reserved space left between the problems are 3cm.

Comment: The OP writes 'preferably that the space I used for these content are "reserved." ' I don't really know what this means tbh, but I interpret it as the space would be white?

Comment: Oh I got it. Let me see something.

Answer (score 3):

Doing this is a lot of work, and that is why there are, as you say, so many options for "Solution/Answer" **packages**. You might actually find a package that fits your need pretty easily; maybe [exercisebank](http://ctan.org/pkg/exercisebank), [xsim](http://ctan.org/pkg/xsim), or some of the other alternatives in the [exercise](https://ctan.org/topic/exercise) and [exam](https://ctan.org/topic/exam) topics on CTAN.

That being said, you can as @Levy says, use the comment package to hide your environment. Maybe the `\vspace` workaround that @Levy suggests could be sufficient, but I couldn't help myself in regards to the automatic height question.

You could use boxes to make sure the height is appropriate. That is, the actual height of the content. Almost.

By defining the `\ProcessCutFile` to be empty then the `comment` package won't do anything (it's all in the [docs](http://ctan.uib.no/macros/latex/contrib/comment/comment.pdf)). Further more, we can use the `\CommentCutFile` to put the content of the environment into a `\box`, which we can get the height of. Then we just apply `\vskip` to push this height.

However, if we want it for multiple pages, I came up with a solution that puts `\vskip 10pt` until it reaches the height of the box. A little hacky, I know.

Only drawbacks are that this height thing would *probably* not work with verbatim environments like e.g. `listings`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Make ourselves a new conditional
\newif\ifDisplaySolutions
% Use \DisplaySolutionstrue to "activate" it
\makeatletter
% Make a solution environment
\generalcomment{solution}{%
  \begingroup
  \ifDisplaySolutions\else%
  % if \DisplaySolutionstrue is not called, then we remove the contents
  \def\ProcessCutFile{}\fi%
}{%
  \ifDisplaySolutions\else%
    % aand,now (also when it's not called), we make a box
    % and then we \input the \CommentCutFile.
    \setbox1=\vbox{\input{\CommentCutFile}}%
    \edef\boxheight{\strip@pt\ht1}
    % Get the height from \ht1 and use \vskip to make appropriate space
    \newcount\Scount
    \Scount=0
    \FPdiv\boxPartHeight{\boxheight}{10}
    {\nullfont\loop\vskip 10pt\relax\advance\Scount by 1 \ifnum\Scount<\boxPartHeight\relax\repeat}
  \fi
\endgroup%
}
\makeatother

%Uncomment below to hide solution
\DisplaySolutionstrue
\begin{document}
Some problem text goes here \lipsum[1]

\begin{solution}
  \textbf{SOLUTION}\lipsum
  \[ \forall\varepsilon>0\exists\delta>0:\dots \]
\end{solution}
Some text after solution.

\end{document}
```

**Edit:** Made it work across pages

Answer (score 2):

I've had good results taking your example and adding `\usepackage{xcolor}`.  Then when I want the student version, I can add the option `bodyfont=\color{white}` to `\declaretheoremstyle{solstyle}`.  The text still exists (so it's probably not safe to give students the electronic pdf), but it is invisible in the output.

Comment: Just had a problem with `figure` enviro. They still appear. But well, not a big deal then. lol

Comment: Also, if I have anything like `ref{XXX}`, there will still be COLOR links.

Comment: In hyperref, I believe you can use `\ref*{XXX}` to get the appropriate reference without a link (it's also possible to pass the `hidelinks` option so that the links aren't colored.